# Django All-auth and rest-auth with Facebook (import fields)

Tags: django, facebook, rest, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I tried to integrate Django REST framework with `django-rest-auth` and `django-allauth`.

Now I can create an user from Facebook using an API rest.

I created this superuser:

```
Name: Barack
Email: barack@mysite.com
Password: hello
```

Ok, I tried to create an user by Facebook using my new REST api.
I used an Facebook user with ***user.name = barack.obama***

After this registration I have open my database:

I see this tables:

[image]

In the User-auth table I have two rows: the first row has ***username=barack*** and the second row has ***username=barack2***

But,why I have username=barack2 about the user created with Facebook? where does this? Why do not uses the Facebook username (barack.obama)?

Is possible to define which fields to recover from Facebook and how to save it?

Is necessary to define something in my settings?

Now I have this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'SocialAuth',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)
```

Using my admin panel I can see this:

[image]

I see Social Accounts: is this a different type of user (sub-type of basic user). Is possible to ass some others field on this user type?

I need to have two different user type:

- Social Accounts (on this type I need to add some others filed: field_X_1 field_X_2....)
- Standard_Accounts (on this type I need to add some other field: field_Y_1, field_Y_2...)

Social Accounts and Standard Account are both subtypes of BasicUser so I need to considered these like User of my app.

*SocialAccounts* can be authenticated only by API Rest (django-rest-auth + Facebook) while *StaandardAccounts* can authenticate only using the admin panel (username / password: classic way)

Is possible to have this?